# Add a facebook login button in login/register page

Tags: 7, social-network

I am using [Simple Fb Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect) module for logging in using facebook. It adds an extra tab for facebook login in my login page but not in register page. I want instead add a button to these pages for facebook login. How can I do that?